# How do I get id number from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Sorry I'm new in Javascript. I wanna get a number from my url in javascript, because I need it very much. I'd got this code from another link but it's not perfect enough for my case. The code is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function kampret(){
            x=location.pathname.split('/')[1];
            alert(x);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='kampret()'>
</body>
</html>
```

My url is like this:

```
http://domain.com/ztest1.php?ai=85&ver=7
```

I want to get that number of '85', and i used that code and the result is **ztest1.php** not 85. And how do i get the only 85? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
//var url = "http://domain.com/ztest1.php?ai=85&ver=7";
var url = window.location.href;
var idx = url.indexOf("?");
var idx2 = url.indexOf("&");
var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+4, idx2) : "";
```

And if you want only the 85 in this code you can use `hash = idx != -1 ? hash.substring(3, idx) : "";`

Comment: how do i get url from above?

Comment: Using`var url = window.location.href;`

Comment: wait a minute, I'll try it.

Comment: the result is **ai=85**, I just need 85

Comment: ooww I see, wait a minute, I'll tested.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer, it's the same but less code.

Comment: It is great, but if you want `ver`, will you rewrite it?

Comment: @VijayaSankarN, I know my answer are not the best option, I vote your answer, for example. But if it works for him...

Comment: @Vijaya, actually I still don't understand perfectly about piterio's code, but I will learn it more later. but by the way don't want **ver**, I just want **ai**, which way do i should to rewrite become **ai** Vijaya based on this code?

Comment: @Piterio please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
var getUrlParams = function (url) 
{
  var params = {};
  (url + '?').split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(
    function (pair) 
    {
       pair = (pair + '=').split('=').map(decodeURIComponent);
       if (pair[0].length) 
       {
         params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
       }
  });

  return params;
};
```

Result is

```
Object {ai: "85", ver: "7"}
```

Usage:

```
// 'http://domain.com/ztest1.php?ai=85&ver=7'
var params = getUrlParams( window.location.href );
alert( params.ai ); // 85
```

Comment: How do i echo that result or alert? sorry I'm new in Java.

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi, it's JavaScript, NO Java

Comment: I have edited the usage. Its not Java, its JavaScript. :)

Comment: ooww sorry, I thought that Java and Javascript is the same. Ok, i'll say javascript then, thanks.

Comment: how do i get the url from above address bar?

Comment: `window.location.href`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, or still don't know how to use it, it still a blank page for me, sorry, how stupid I'm :`( , but I keep give you +1.

Comment: No problem, you can edit your question with the current code. Then we can better help you

Comment: wait, I'm curious, I'll keep trying this @mischaZeng's code.

Comment: Baaaam, I made it @mishaZeng. It works now. Actually i couldn't read your code, it's still too complicated for me. But I will learn it in google word by word from your code. Thanks again MishaZeng, +9 for you.

Comment: @mischaZeng please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(getURLParameter('ai'));
}); //JQuery

window.onload = alert(getURLParameter('ai')); //JavaScript
```

Adopted for yours:

```
<body onload='kampret()'></body>
<script>
    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
    }

    function kampret() {
        alert(getURLParameter('ai'));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and if you want `ver` simply you can use like this: `getURLParameter('ver')`

Comment: 1st code, there's no result, just blank. 2nd code, the alert shows up but only written **NULL**

Comment: its `getURLParameter('ai')` not `getURLParameter('a')`

Comment: By the way both the codes are same. First code has JQuery, so you need to add CDN for it

Comment: It works now. Thank you @Vijaya. Ouww, JQuery, ok wait, I'll try it again.

Comment: That's fine, and it is just a single line function you can use it with ease

Comment: Wow, you are right @Vijaya. After i put CDN then It works also. Thanks you vijaya, +1 for you.

Comment: please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 1):

A smaller way using php and javascript.

```
<?php $id = $_GET['ai']; ?>
<script language="javascript">
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
alert(id);
</script>
```

Comment: It can be even as simple as `alert(<?php echo $_GET['ai']; ?>);`

Comment: Haha yes I know but just explaining it a little :D

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll try it.

Comment: wow, it works @Ali, thanks for your code, I'll keep it in my library. +1 for you also.

Comment: Thankyou @Junaserbaserbi :)

Comment: @Ali please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)